# chromium v44 + netflix : missing components error

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, streaming, plugin, chromium-os

1) I installed chromium beta v44 on linux mint 17 (rebecca) as per discussion here:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

2) I copied `libwidevinecdm.so` and `libwidevinecdmadapter.so` into `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/` folder. I retrieved these libraries from the tar file below which was posted as an attachment to bug `1371274`.

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274/+attachment/4397708/+files/WidevineLinuxForChromium44.tar.gz
```

3) I see the following library when I go to chrome://plugins

```
Widevine Content Decryption Module
Enables Widevine licenses for playback of HTML audio/video content.
```

4) If I try to view a netflix film I get the redirects error:

```
Netflix - Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

5) HOWEVER, if I change the user-agent

from:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.30 Chrome/44.0.2403.30 Safari/537.36
```

To (tricking netflix to think browser is google chrome):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.30 Safari/537.36
```

I don't get the re-directs error but instead netflix throws back the following missing components error:

```
We cannot find all the required components to play Netflix on this device. Please visit chrome://components, locate the WidewineCdm component, and click the "Check for update" button.
```

If I go to chrome://components I do NOT see the WidewineCdm component there although I do see it in chrome://plugins.

Any idea how to get this working - either without modifying the user-agent or after modifying it?

**UPDATE**

Output of `ldd /usr/lib/chromium-browser libwidevine*`

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser:
ldd: /usr/lib/chromium-browser: not regular file
libwidevinecdmadapter.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd45fe000)
    libwidevinecdm.so => /home/bean/Downloads/./libwidevinecdm.so (0x00007f167c164000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f167be41000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f167bc22000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f167b85d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f167b557000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f167b340000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f167c902000)
libwidevinecdm.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff65fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff82d878000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff82d574000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff82d35d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff82d13f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff82cd7a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff82e326000)
```

Comment: anyone here know who I can contact to get help?

Comment: Can you try downloading Chrome Dev (version 45) and copying the binaries from there?

Comment: I tried to remove the beta Chromium (v44) so I can install the Chrome Dev (v45) you suggested but I can't ppa-purge it. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213818/cant-ppa-purge-ppasaiarcot895-chromium-beta

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using `chromium-dev` instead of `chromium-beta`. In that case, Widevine should have worked.

Comment: was using chromium-beta v44. Not working. Next steps?

Comment: My version of Chromium = Version 44.0.2403.30 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17.1 (64-bit)

Comment: the other question is why wasn't i able to remove the chromium-beta when I invoked ppa-purge?

Comment: I removed the browser using 'sudo apt-get purge' and then a 'sudo apt-get autoremove'. I re-installed the browser. This time the newest beta version is "Version 44.0.2403.61 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17.1 (64-bit)". I get the same problem with netflix. Components are missing.

Comment: i copied the widevine libs to /usr/lib/chromium-browser.

Comment: I don't know about `ppa-purge` in Linux Mint; you might need to remove the entry manually from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` As for widevine, just out of curiosity, when running `ldd /usr/lib/chromium-browser libwidevine*`, are there any undefined references?

Comment: Please see updated post for output of ldd command. As a side, not sure why it references the downloaded copy:     *libwidevinecdm.so => /home/bean/Downloads/./libwidevinecdm.so (0x00007f167c164000)*

Comment: That's because I made an error in the command, and because of the space between `/usr/lib/chromium-browser` and `libwidevine*`, the libraries in your current directory were used. Nevertheless, the output looks good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25527/discussion-between-codingknob-and-saiarcot895).

Comment: So I guess netflix is not workable on linux mint? Are there any Linux Mint users here who use Netflix on their devices? There is a large install base of Linux Mint so I'd assume that there are many nflx users who use it on that OS. Anyone?

Comment: It should be possible to use Netflix in Linux Mint. I can't personally test it because I don't have a Netflix account, but Ekimia in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274) bug report was able to get it working.

Comment: Its not clear from bug 1371274 that the OS is Linux Mint. The only reference to Mint in that bug report is made by the last post in the thread and thats me.